# How can i set two columns primary key in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, primary-key

I wanna set two primary key(id and Android_id)  in my table (etat_terminals)
so there is a problem.
PS: Android_id is type string
this is migration of etat_terminals:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('etat_terminals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('Android_id');
            $table->string('NiveauDeBatterie')->nullable();
            $table->string('Memoire')->nullable();
            $table->string('Lattitude')->nullable();
            $table->string('Longitude')->nullable();
            $table->string('Fabriquant')->nullable();
            $table->string('Modele')->nullable();
            $table->string('VersionSE')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

this is migration of terminals:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('terminals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('Android_id')->unique();
            $table->string('nom')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('Android_id')->references('Android_id')->on('etat_terminals');
        });
    }
```

and this my model:

```
class EtatTerminal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'etat_terminals';

    protected $fillable = [
        'Android_id',
        'NiveauDeBatterie',
        'Memoire',
        'Lattitude',
        'Longitude',
        'Fabriquant',
        'Modele',
        'VersionSE'
    ];
    public $timestamp = false;

    public function terminal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Terminal::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Terminal extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Android_id',
        'nom'
    ];
    public $timestamp = false;

    public function etats_terminal()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EtatTerminal::class);
    }
}
```

the error is :
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'etat_terminals' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'terminals_android_id_foreign'. (SQL: alter table "terminals" add constraint "terminals_android_id_foreign" foreign key ("Android_id") references "etat_terminals" ("Android"))

Comment: Try to migrate:fresh - as I see in error - you change key in foreign from Android to Android_id

Comment: i tried migrate:fresh but it's the same error